# $\mathcal{A} = \left\{ A \subset \mathbb{N} ; \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \#(A \cap \{1,\ldots,n\}) \text{ exists} \right\}$ is not a algebra

Tags: combinatorics, measure-theory

I must show that the set $$\mathcal{A} = \left\{ A \subset \mathbb{N} ; \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \#(A \cap \{1,\ldots,n\}) \text{ exists} \right\}$$
is not a algebra.

It's easy to see that $\emptyset,\mathbb{N}\in \mathcal{A}$ and that if $A \in \mathcal{A}$ then $\mathbb{N}-A \in \mathcal{A}$. So I must find $A, B \in \mathcal{A}$ with $A \cup B \notin \mathcal{A}$.   I'm having problems simply finding a set that is not contained in $\mathcal{A}$. From my understanding the limit is, in some way, representing the "presence of A" in $\mathbb{N}$ as I look upon arbitrarily large natural numbers.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think the point here is that it is not closed under countable union, instead of arguing with finite union. Since if you take finite union, $\#((A\cup B)\cap \{1,\cdots,n\})$ is always less than $n$. I think things will change under countable union...

Comment: It definitely isn't closed under countable union, because on the contrary we would have $\mathcal{A} = \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$.

Comment: then you solved the problem right? if not closed under countable union, then it is not a $\sigma-$algebra.

Comment: You've shown that it's not a $\sigma$-algebra, but the problem was to prove that it's not an algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to "just do it". We will define $A$ and $B$ by hand so that $A$ and $B$ both have density $1/2$ but $A \cup B$ has undefined density. Let $N_1 < N_2 < N_3 < \cdots$ be a sequence of larger and larger scales such that $N_{k+1} / N_k \to \infty$, say $N_k = k!$. On $[N_{k-1}, N_k)$ with $k$ even let $A$ and $B$ both consist of all even numbers. On $[N_{k-1}, N_k)$ with $k$ odd let $A$ be all even numbers and $B$ all odd numbers. Now if you measure the density of $A \cup B$ in $\{1, \dots, N\}$, the question is how much do $A$ and $B$ overlap, and that massively depends on what interval $[N_{k-1}, N_k)$ contains $N$. I'll leave the remaining details to you.

Comment: "The idea is to "just do it"". Really?

Comment: That was a reference to the idea that sometimes it's a good idea to just jump in and start constructing rather than to try to come up with something special. See https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~wtg10/justdoit.html

Comment: "He tells me that he and a few others invented it after supervisions with Béla Bollobás, who would occasionally ask, when they got stuck, `Why don't you just do it?'" Ha! Thanks for that link.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be the set of even integers and define $J: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ at an $n$ by letting $k$ be the unique integer such that $2^k\leq n<2^{k+1}$ and let $J(n)$ be $2n$ if $k$ is even and $2n-1$ if $k$ is odd. Putting $B:=J(\mathbb{N})$ we see that $|(A\cup B)\cap\{1,\cdots ,n\}|/n$ will in fact oscillate between $2/3$ and $5/6$.

Comment: How can I show that $B \in \mathcal{A}$?

Comment: The point is that $B$ will roughly contain the first even number (2), then the two next odd numbers (3 and 5), then roughly the next four even numbers (8, 10, 12 and 14), then the next eight odd numbers and so on.  So for $B$ the limit will be $1/2$